# Heroku completely ignores config.toml file

Tags: python, heroku, config, streamlit

I just made my website using streamlit and have uploaded it to heroku.
I have a config.toml file in the .streamlit folder, which changes the text colour and background colour of the website.

On running it by using the `streamlit run` command, it works perfectly fine. But using heroku and going to the provided website, the text colour there seems to be black and the background white, which are not the correct colours.

Here is my `setup.sh` file:

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/

echo "\
[general]\n\
email = \"myname@domain.com\"\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/credentials.toml

echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
enableCORS=false\n\
port = $PORT\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

Here is my `config.toml` file:

```
[theme]
primaryColor = '#eb4034'
backgroundColor = '#021d24'
secondaryBackgroundColor = '#B9F1C0'
textColor = '#FFFFFF'
font = "sans serif"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is my `config.toml` file

I'm not sure where that content comes from, but it won't be in your `config.toml` on Heroku because you create or overwrite that file in your `setup.sh`.

`echo`ing stuff and redirecting it into a file using `>` overwrites what's already there.

If that file already exists (unlikely on Heroku, but I'm not familiar with Streamlit so maybe it gets generated somehow), change `>` to `>>` so you *append to* the existing file instead:

```bash
echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
enableCORS=false\n\
port = $PORT\n\
" >> ~/.streamlit/config.toml  # <-- Here
```

Or, add the `[theme]` section to your `setup.sh` (note the change to single quotes around `#FFFFFF`):

```bash
echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
enableCORS=false\n\
port = $PORT\n\
\n\
[theme]\n\
primaryColor = '#eb4034'\n\
backgroundColor = '#021d24'\n\
secondaryBackgroundColor = '#B9F1C0'\n\
textColor = '#FFFFFF'\n\
font = 'sans serif'\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```